# Error when viewing Google App Engine application after deployment

Tags: java, eclipse

I used Eclipse to work through the Google App Engine tutorial to create a guestbook. Everything works fine on my local machine within the Eclipse environment. I successfully deployed the application to Google App Engine.
When I visit the URL (http://dcsnetlink-guestbook.appspot.com/) to see my application, I get the following error.

Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it

I did some research on the web to resolve this, but have been thus far unsuccessful.
Please help.

Here's what's in the log on Google App Engine pertaining to this.

### Google App Engine Log entry for Guestbook - May 5th, 2012

‹ Prev 20 1-19 Next 20 › (Top: 0:00:09 ago)
2012-05-05 17:05:14.891 /favicon.ico 304 10ms 0kb
97.90.234.201 - - [05/May/2012:17:05:14 -0700] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 0 - - "dcsnetlink-guestbook.appspot.com" ms=10 cpu_ms=0 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000045 
2012-05-05 17:05:14.726 / 500 3096ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19
97.90.234.201 - - [05/May/2012:17:05:14 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19" "dcsnetlink-guestbook.appspot.com" ms=3096 cpu_ms=1419 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.039468 loading_request=1 instance=00c61b117cd052a13542bd8aeb337bc0ae68268e
W 2012-05-05 17:05:14.643
Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@1a3b359{/,/base/data/home/apps/s~dcsnetlink-guestbook/1.358537445667406021}
org.mortbay.util.MultiException[java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: guestbook/GuestbookServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0, java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: guestbook/SignGuestbookServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:656)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:202)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:171)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:123)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: guestbook/GuestbookServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-2dd9d02a5e2a506c(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: guestbook/SignGuestbookServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-2dd9d02a5e2a506c(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
C 2012-05-05 17:05:14.720
Uncaught exception from servlet
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Initialization failed.
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:211)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:171)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:123)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
I 2012-05-05 17:05:14.725
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.

Thanks,
Samuel

Comment: Is there anything in the [logs](https://appengine.google.com/logs?&app_id=s~dcsnetlink-guestbook) you can see on Dashboard?

Comment: the information that you have given in your question doesn't help us to come up with any solution. For eg. how did you deploy your application? and as @PhilippReichart said, is there anything in the log files?

Comment: I will check into the log files. As far as deployment, I did that using the Google Plugin for Eclipse. Thanks!

Comment: Here is what in the logs on Google App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: guestbook/GuestbookServlet :
>   Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

This Cause if you Compiled java classes using JRE 1.7 (jre7)

Solution are:

1. Downgrade JDK in to JDK6
2. Change project "Compiler compliance level"
   to 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

If you used Java 1.8, you have to recompile with Java 1.7. But if you have *.jsp files, you should also completely remove Java 1.8 from the system. If you use Mac, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039752/removing-java-8-from-mac) is how you can do it.