# Java unsupported major minor version 52.0

Tags: java, html, applet

I can not launch my java application as a web applet in HTML (I am using HTML 4.01, I know it doesn't work in html5). The error message it returns is:

> java : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

I have tried downgrading my java JRE/JDK/SDK but I still get the same error message. The current version of java I am now using is 1.8.0_05.

Comment: Look at the loooooong list of related questions on the right.

Comment: that is the 51.0 version, and I have tried the solutions

Comment: You must compile for an old version of the JRE, the one you run in your browser. This is done by using the `target` parameter. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html#options

Comment: I will take a look at that now

Comment: I cant seem to -target the JRE like you said it seems to want the sdk

Comment: You current version is almost certainly not 1.8.0_05. Try http://www.javatester.org/version.html

Comment: when I type in java -version into cmd thats what it comes out with

Comment: Maybe it is a duplicate, but searching for the 52.0 message error take me here.

Comment: Simply set your environment variable Java home to the new version of java.. that solves the probelm

Comment: Consider accepting the top answer.  Even though this is a dup you can check it off if it was helpful.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Your code was compiled with Java Version 1.8 while it is being executed with Java Version 1.7 or below.

In your case it seems that two different Java installations are used, the newer to compile and the older to execute your code.

Try recompiling your code with Java 1.7 or upgrade your Java Plugin.

Comment: I have done all of that and now the error is "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"

Comment: I had this problem when using the Stanford Parser jars. Thanks @Leonard

Comment: Linux/Mac check `echo $JAVA_HOME` if it's not pointing to Java 7 folder

Comment: For Windows use this `echo %JAVA_HOME%` to check for Java_Home path.

Answer (score 7):

You have to compile with Java 1.7. But if you have *.jsp files, you should also completely remove Java 1.8 from the system. If you use Mac, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039752/removing-java-8-from-mac) is how you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that in netbeans Apache configuration in the servers tab. you can state the platform for your web application. I changed to 1.8 and it worked fine. (I am targeting java 8 platform in my application). Hope that might t help.

Answer (score 2):

I assumed openjdk8 would work with tomcat8 but I had to remove it and keep openjdk7 only, this fixed the issue in my case. I really don't know why or if there is something else I could have done.