# Java distribution not working

Tags: java, exception, build

I made a simple quiz `jFrame` application in netbeans. I built the project to a executable jar and it runs perfectly on my computer. When i try send it it then just says A Java Exception has occurred. So I ran it from the command prompt and it says :

> Exception in the thread 'main' java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   Frame: Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

I am using custom images for a background and buttons. Where should i place those? They arent in the dist folder. They were added to a scr folder when netbeans imported them.

Comment: You're using the wrong Java version...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 Exception` occure with your compilation version not match with your previous compilation version. you have to change your java version.

If you are using Eclipse go to Windows ---> Prefences then select Java and expand it then select Compiler and change the compliance level to *[your JDK version]* then try to compile your code with *[your JDK version]*.

Refer,
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24790834/cant-fix-unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0-even-after-fixing-compatibility) 
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23249331/java-unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is compatible with `Jre8` while you are running it with `Jre7` which is creating problem.Change/Set `JRE_HOME` for `Jre8` before running the program.

Comment: It is not clear if the other computer used Java 1.7^^. The same error message will occure, when  Java 1.6 and older is used (at least until 1.4).