# visual studio 2015: "Unsupported class version error" in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin-studio

I just downloaded Xamarin for visual studio 2015. I did everything written in xamarin website. But when i try to build an android app, it shows an "Unsupported class version \ Unsupported Major.Minor Version" error. How can i fix it?

[Screenshot of error report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAfke.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java unsupported major minor version 52.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23249331/java-unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)

Answer (score 0):

This error is related with the manifest.
Can you show us the manifest for your app ?