# Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException)

Tags: java, tomcat, solr, lucene

When I use Tomcat 7.0.73 and Solr 6.4.1 to code something on a servlet, ERRORs like this occured,

"**java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrServerException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException)**",

I do believe this has nothing to do with code, but a specific Class named SolrServerException. Anyone can tell me how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: It usually means that the java code was compiled to a later version of java than the jvm that is trying to run it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23249331/java-unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0