# I have trouble uninstalling Java 8 (MAC)

Tags: java, macos

I have installed Java 1.8.0_20 & I can't uninstall it. I have no Java folder in my Library so any other walkthroughs have been useless & every time I switch the preferred order it just sets back to normal as soon as I close Java preferences. I need like a terminal command or folder to go to manually delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is due to the fact that Oracle took no care now that they are owners of the Mac version (since 1.6). This is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039752/removing-java-8-from-mac).

Answer (score 0):

Try these terminal commands:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<version>.jdk
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
sudo rm -rf /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
```