# Move usr/bin/java in Terminal

Tags: java, macos, terminal, rename, zimbra

After updating to OS X 10.11, my java stopped working. I read multiple places that I should do a:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/java /usr/bin/java.old
sudo ln -ns /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java /usr/bin/java
```

But the issue is when I run the first line of code, I just get:

```
mv: rename /usr/bin/java to /usr/bin/java.old: Operation not permitted
```

Any ideas what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Seems like the problem with the new [System Integration Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) (a.k.a rootless) that just got introduced with the new OS X.

You could try to disable the rootless in recovery mode through these steps :

1. go to recovery mode (reboot and hold down <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> keys simultaneously after you hear the startup chime)
2. When the “OS X Utilities” screen appears, pull down the ‘Utilities’ menu at the top of the screen instead, and choose “Terminal”
3. run this command `csrutil disable;reboot`. This will reboot the laptop.

After that. Then, try to run the command again and see what will happen :D.

Comment: How can I re-enable it?

Comment: @Isuru try 'csrutil enable'