# JDK does not show

Tags: macos, java-8

I'm running Xamarin 6.0.2 on Mac OS X El Capitan. I've installed Java version 8 and confirmed that it is running. However, when I attempt to point Xamarin (via tools >> SDK Manager) to the JDK for Java, the JDK file does not appear.

I confirmed the location of the JAVA sdk via terminal, which displayed the following: **/usr/bin/java** ...but no JDK

Manually via Finder, (command-shift-G) -  I entered /usr/bin/java, the file displays, but it does not when I navigate there via Xamarin SDK manager

I also tried navigating to: **Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines**/   ...but it just appears blank. (I've un-hidden all my files via terminal)

Could I please get some assistance as to what I may be doing wrong or over-looking?
...thanks in advance

Comment: I actually located the file 'Java_home' here: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/     ...but it is dimmed out, could this be a permissions issue? any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/bin/java` is a symbolic link, it's not the location of the Java SDK.
First check correctly the location of your JDK path with:
`/usr/libexec/java_home -V`
If it's showing you the path of JDK8 then you need to insert it in Xamarin under 
SDK Locations -> Android -> Java SDK.
 If it's not showing the JDK path, it seems to be a problem with your JDK installation.

I would suggest you to uninstall it correctly (thanks to Samuel Alpoim [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039752/removing-java-8-jdk-from-mac))

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<version>.jdk
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
sudo rm -rf /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
sudo rm -rf /Library/LaunchAgents/com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist
sudo rm -rf /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.oracle.java.JavaUpdateHelper
sudo rm -rf /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist
sudo rm -rf /Library/Preferences/com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist
```

and perform a new install of the JDK.
If you need to have multiple JDK versions make sure to check and export the correct version in the environment variable with:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
```