# installed Java SDK 8 on macOS (10.12.3) in wrong directory

Tags: java, macos, hadoop, sdk, environment-variables

Appologies for asking new question but I am not allowed to comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039752/removing-java-8-jdk-from-mac).

I need to install Java sdk, and then create an enviroment variable JAVA_HOME pointing to the directory of the java compiler (javac).

I installed java sdl, but installation is not under /Library/Java?... but

here:
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/javac

I need to later on install hadoop and create a new enviroment variable pointing to the location of /lib/tools.jar in my java installation, but this is not to be found in my mac. I searced google and came across link above, but I wasn't allowed to comment.

All solutions suggest that Java should be installed in Library, but this is not my case. I do not know how to delete JAva sdk and try to reinstall it, since oracle's instructions take into account proper installation of java sdk.

Any idea how to proper uninstall/install sdk in order to find tools.jar?

I have created a JAVA_HOME enviroment variable as bellow:

```
javac -version
```

javac 1.8.0_121

```
which java
```

/usr/bin/java

my enviroment variable was created using:
`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to properly install it using homebrew (credits to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342886/how-to-install-java-8-on-mac) answer)

```
brew update
brew cask install java
```

Now I can find my Java folder under Library, and consequently locate lib/tools.jar

Nevertheless I did not remove previous install, so I am not sure what this may cause in the near future.