# Jenkins: FATAL: Could not initialize class hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixReflection

Tags: android, ios, jenkins, java-9

```
FATAL: Could not initialize class hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixReflection
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixReflection
at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.kill(ProcessTree.java:647)
at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.killRecursively(ProcessTree.java:668)
at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.killRecursively(ProcessTree.java:667)
at hudson.util.ProcessTree$Unix.killAll(ProcessTree.java:589)
at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.kill(Launcher.java:949)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:502)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1737)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
```

Jenkins ver. 2.73.3
MacOSx

Doing an iOS build and upload to hockeyapp.  The .ipa is created successfully, error seems to happen afterwards, seems like on the hockeyapp upload.  I have an android project that works and uploads to hockeyapp successfully though.

Started getting this today after updating Jenkins and plugins.  Was working before.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like it has been hacking into a private method in the implementation but the implementation has been refactored in JDK 9 so that private method no longer exists. Best to check the Jenkins issue tracker, maybe it has been logged or fixed already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

happened to me when running an Android build 
(Jenkins build 2.86, I just downgraded from 2.87 or something slighlty newer, because of other fails)

```
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to SUCCESS
FATAL: Could not initialize class 
hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixReflection
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class 
hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixReflection
at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.kill(ProcessTree.java:647)
at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.killRecursively(ProcessTree.java:668)
at hudson.util.ProcessTree$Unix.killAll(ProcessTree.java:589)
at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.kill(Launcher.java:949)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:510)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1724)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
Finished: FAILURE
```

first SUCCESS then FAILURE, hmm weeeird

I remembered that recently I have installed java 9 for experimenting, but still having java 8 set to usl/libexec/java_home, in my .zshrc like:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_152`
```

but that did not help at all, so I said goodbye to Java 9 with

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk
```

then went to Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Environment variables
 and added

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home
```

as JAVA_HOME

after Jenkins restart my builds run like a charm

Comment: Ok, yes looks like Java 9 was installed and that seems suspicious. Working on removing it and testing again.

Comment: Finally got it working again, I had to uninstall java 9 but also update java 8 to the latest version.  Looks like I wanted to fix another issue by updating java and tried java 9 but ran into this problem after updating my jenkins plugins.  At any rate, using the latest java 8 (1.8.0_151 currently) seems to have resolved the problem.

Comment: @CodeSmith How to un-install and install java version 8? Need urgent help.

Comment: @pkc456 your question lacks basic information, such as which operating system you are on... if you are on OSX you can try doing it similarly as in my answer above

Comment: 10.13.3 Mac Operating system

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039752/removing-java-8-jdk-from-mac

Answer (score 0):

While staying with Java 8, wiping the current workspace on Jenkins got rid of the error for me. Got the error after updating gradle and the sonarqube plugin version.

Answer (score 0):

we've been seeing this intermittently on an old Jenkins server and I think we've tracked it down.  It happens when there are background processes left after a job runs and can be easily reproduced with this job script:

```
sleep 30 &
exit 0
```

The error `Could not initialize class hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixReflection` comes from this static initializer:

```
        static {
            try {
                Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("java.lang.UNIXProcess");
                PID_FIELD = clazz.getDeclaredField("pid");
                PID_FIELD.setAccessible(true);

                if (isPreJava8()) {
                    DESTROY_PROCESS = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("destroyProcess",int.class);
                } else {
                    DESTROY_PROCESS = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("destroyProcess",int.class, boolean.class);
                }
                DESTROY_PROCESS.setAccessible(true);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                LinkageError x = new LinkageError();
                x.initCause(e);
                throw x;
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                LinkageError x = new LinkageError();
                x.initCause(e);
                throw x;
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                LinkageError x = new LinkageError();
                x.initCause(e);
                throw x;
            }
        }
```

The signature of `UNIXProcess.destoryProcess` changed in Java 8.  Java 9 and forward may have made further changes.  You'll need a JDK that has what Jenkins wants to find in that class.