# Error while uploading ipa to hockeyapp via jenkins

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hockeyapp

I am working with `jenkins` for auto deployment of iOS app via hockey app. I am successful in creating the .ipa file.

In the post-buid action at jenkin, I set up the `API Token`, App File and other setting. Please look into the attached image for more details. However in the console output, I am getting the below error:-

**Console output :**

> 18:36:11 ** EXPORT SUCCEEDED ** 18:36:11  18:36:11 Archiving dSYM
>   18:36:11 [Release-iphoneos] $ ditto -c -k --keepParent -rsrc
>   /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/jenkinadhocIPA/build/Release-iphoneos/jenkinadhoc.xcarchive/dSYMs/jenkinadhoc.app.dSYM
>   /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/jenkinadhocIPA/build/Release-iphoneos/artifact/2018.06.06-dSYM.zip
>   18:36:11 FATAL: Could not initialize class
>   hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixReflection 18:36:11
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixReflection 18:36:11   at
>   hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.kill(ProcessTree.java:647)
>   18:36:11  at
>   hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.killRecursively(ProcessTree.java:668)
>   18:36:11  at
>   hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.killRecursively(ProcessTree.java:667)
>   18:36:11  at
>   hudson.util.ProcessTree$Unix.killAll(ProcessTree.java:589) 18:36:11
>     at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.kill(Launcher.java:949) 18:36:11   at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:510)
>   18:36:11  at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1724) 18:36:11     at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43) 18:36:11  at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
>   18:36:11  at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421) 18:36:11
>   Build step 'Upload to HockeyApp' marked build as failure 18:36:11
>   Finished: FAILURE

Java version in my system:-

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously a Java problem in the jenkins. You might have to check the JDK and jenkins setup that you are using.

You can reference the following.

[Jenkins: FATAL: Could not initialize class hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixReflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47340751/jenkins-fatal-could-not-initialize-class-hudson-util-processtreeunixreflectio)

Comment: I am using Java version 10 and latest jenkin. Can you please tell me the which version is in accordance with each other.

Comment: I am using Java version 10 and latest jenkin. Can you please tell me the which version is in accordance with each other.