# How to downgrade the java version in mac

Tags: java, macos, jenkins

My current java version details:-

[image]

I followed the steps which are mentioned in the [official java web site](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml). Below are related steps screenshot:-

[image]

After executing these commands, the java version remains the same. I want to downgrade the java version, because I am facing issue with [hockey app plugin in jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50721336/error-while-uploading-ipa-to-hockeyapp-via-jenkins).

- Do I need to restart my system?
- Do I need to perform other steps? If yes, what are those?

Comment: Instead of downgrading the built-in java, it should be easier to just install a separate instance of an older Java version somewhere else, then configure Jenkins to run using that version explicitly. See: https://serverfault.com/q/858748

Answer (score 4):

First run /usr/libexec/java_home -V which will output something like the following:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
1.8.0_05, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home
1.6.0_65-b14-462, x86_64:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
1.6.0_65-b14-462, i386: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Pick the version you want to be the default (1.6.0_65-b14-462 for arguments sake) then:

export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6.0_65-b14-462`
or you can specify just the major version, if it's unique, like

export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
Now when you run java -version you will see:

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

Just add the export JAVA_HOME… line to your shell’s init file.