# Xamarin: Java SDK doesn't contain a valid version number

Tags: java, xamarin, xamarin.forms, javac

I'm not able to build app for android because I get a Warning:

Failed to get the Java SDK version as it does not appear to contain a valid version number. `javac -version` returned: ```java version "10" 2018-03-20.

and an Error:

Error MSB4044: The "AdjustJavacVersionArguments" task was not given a value for the required parameter "JdkVersion".

It was fine before I downloaded newer version  of Java, jdk-10. The old version which seem to be working was jdk-1.8.

Comment: Java 10.0.1 has been released. It returns a proper version number.

Comment: @wasatchwizard Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have the right path of JDK in the `Android Settings` tab, on Windows should be something like: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152`

Comment: I've Mac, the default path for JDK is  `/usr` and on the right side of the input text field there's a green tick saying 'Found'.

Comment: That's the symbolic link, try /usr/libexec/java_home -V to have the right path, if there is something wrong the fastest option is to delete properly the JDK installation (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039752/removing-java-8-jdk-from-mac) and reinstall it, exporting the version you need.

Comment: yes, I had to select the 'home' folder, it works now, thank you.