# can't run sbt because of SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: sbt

I just install sbt using `brew install sbt`. However, I got a weird error when I tried `sbt` the first time for  `sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException`...

The error looks like

[info] [launcher] getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.9.7  (this may take some time)...
[error] [launcher] xsbt.boot.internal.shaded.coursier.error.ResolutionError$CantDownloadModule: Error downloading org.scala-sbt:sbt:1.9.7
not found: /Users/username/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.9.7/ivys/ivy.xml
download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException (PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target) while downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.9.7/sbt-1.9.7.pom
download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException (PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target) while downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.9.7/sbt-1.9.7.pom
download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException (PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target) while downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.9.7/sbt-1.9.7.pom
download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException (PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target) while downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.9.7/ivys/ivy.xml
download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException (PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target) while downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.9.7/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] [launcher] could not retrieve sbt 1.9.7

I tried to reinstall sbt using sdk, but still get the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix SSL error when downloading plugin via SBT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56841928/how-to-fix-ssl-error-when-downloading-plugin-via-sbt)

Comment: In my personal experience, I prefer to use coursier or sdkman. These tools let's install and select different versions of Scala and sbt

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to the JDK I used (which provided by eBay). i.e., The context is that eBay has their own version of OpenSDK... So, it is not a general issue I realized.

Comment: Additional information for anyone has same issue. It actually lacks some certification in JDK, so have to manually input `./bin/keytool`