# How do I remove java properly from my mac?

Tags: java, macos, terminal

so I am on a mac and I wanted to remove java, as I do not need it on my computer. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039752/removing-java-8-jdk-from-mac) and it doesn't work: the version I wanted to remove still came up when I typed `java -version` or `java --version` and I don't think this should come up. Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: Did you try the [official documentation](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml) ?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to run the remove command (rm) as root or by using sudo (as opposed to removing Java tools from /usr/bin, which you should *not* do).

The specific steps are shown [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml) on Oracle's site.

Comment: This didn't work, it still showed the same output, I tried restarting my computer and it still didn't work

Comment: Does the output from the rm command indicate success or failure/error?

Comment: I think it does, as it asks for the systems password