# How do I uninstall other/older java versions from my Mac?

Tags: java, macos, java-8, java-14

I currently have java 8 (1.8.0_261) on my Mac that I use with IntelliJ. But my college requires the latest java, so I installed java 14.0.1 today. How do I uninstall java 8 from my Mac, as I won’t be needing it anymore. Thank you for taking your time to read this.

Comment: You can switch between multiple java versions in Mac. Here is similar question answered : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252591/mac-os-x-and-multiple-java-versions

Comment: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing Java 8 JDK from Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039752/removing-java-8-jdk-from-mac)

Answer (score 3):

Go to terminal and type:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<desired_version>.jdk
```