# uninstall openjdk in mac

Tags: java, uninstallation

I did navigate to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines and removed the jdk, and there is nothing in that folder anymore. But my terminal shows I have some version of java, so I am a little confused, I wanna uninstall java completely from my laptop. I did uninstall JRE too using a set of commands.

steps to reproduce

java -version

output:

openjdk version "1.8.0_152-release"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: You might find this post interesting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039752/removing-java-8-jdk-from-mac

Comment: use `which java` and check where the `java` command comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you still have files left in another folder. look up where file of the jdk are also stored.

Comment: Look up this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-macos.htm#JSJIG-GUID-577CEA7C-E51C-416D-B9C6-B1469F45AC78
Maybe it helps to remove everything in the /Library/Internet Plug-Ins and Library/PreferencePanes folders that is associated with jre

Comment: Maybe, you cant unsinstall the jdk 1 completely because the system needs at least one jdk installed. But I am not sure of this. May i ask why you want to uninstall this jdk version?

Comment: And have you rebooted your system after doing all this?

Comment: I am uninstalling to install jdk8 once this is removed.. and yes I have rebooted system after doing this

Comment: you dont have to uninstall any jdk to install another one. For example I have JDK 1,8,11,13 and 14 installed you can later configure your PATH to wich version you want to use. Dont uninstall this version maybe you need it one day.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps: To Uninstall Java completely from your System.

1. Click on the Finder icon located in your dock
2. Click on the Utilities folder.
3. Double-click on the Terminal icon

In the Terminal window Copy and Paste the commands below:

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/Java
```

Comment: The issue is in MAC and not windows so this will not help